# Is this possible to enable Einstein ChatBot in Developer org

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein, chat

Is this possible to enable Einstein ChatBot in Developer org. If yes then how we can enabled it and if no then what is the solution.

Comment: Yes you can now activate it in sandboxes. You need the digital enhancement package. The activation is done by Salesforce, so you need to create a case to them.

Answer (score 1):

[image]No Einstein CHatBot is not available in Developer Org.

You can still try this in Summer 18 Pre-Release Org for free. Pre-release orgs are just a more advanced form of developer org that help you play with release even before it is available in sandboxes.

https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-summer18.jsp